# In my console I have this weird uncaught referenceError..(using XAMPP)

Tags: http, xampp

I was working earlier for a future project inside of XAMPP. I always take a look at my console to, well you know, errors, problems, etc..And Just a few minutes ago, I had this new Uncaught ReferenceError and this file is not mine. Is this any kind of hacking, or something? 'Cause i'm kinda worried right now... lol.

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=tcxmgdl&userId=ZUE+D5XtRYy5RfHKPWs95Q==&ctid=1049999". gsrs?is=s32chsbca&bp=PB&g=65413e0f-95ed-458c-b945-f1ca3d6b3de5:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: syrng_boot is not defined tv-classic-fg.js:1
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://jsl.infostatsvc.com/?PageVisitCounter_1=PB_BetterBrowse|,|65413e0f-95ed-458c-b945-f1ca3d6b3de5". gscs:3
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://jsl.infostatsvc.com/?PageVisit_2=PB_BetterBrowse|,|65413e0f-95ed-45…lhost%2Fajax%2Findex.php|,|1395796226510|,|1395796226542|,|274|,||,||,||,|". gscs:3
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://jsl.infostatsvc.com/?PanelPageVisit_3=PB_BetterBrowse|,|65413e0f-95…st%2Fajax%2Findex.php|,||,|1395796226510|,|1395796226542|,|274|,||,||,||,|". gscs:3
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "https://jsl.infostatsvc.com/?GcUrlVisit_2=55353296|,|65413e0f-95ed-458c-b94…|274|,|1395880828719|,|BetterBrowse|,|be7ccf05-5804-10fb-5a95-4e814ba032b0".
```

Syrng_boot is not defined...what the f is that? I mean, I have no syrng_boot inside my files..neither a file named tv-classic-fg.js:1 ...

Comment: I'm doing some client side JavaScript development, and I started seeing this too. It's making me wonder if my web server was compromised. Please update this as you find anymore information, and I'll try to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same thing. It is Mega Browser Ads, which is SUPPOSED to be removed pretty easily by following [these instructions](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/mega-browse-virus-removal/). I installed a program called CamStudio for screen recording, which I think came bundled with that crapware.

After I followed all those steps, I actually had to uninstall, and reinstall Chrome. Then, it finally looked like I cleaned this mess up.